# Are there any C functions for extracting substring from a text file as a struct?

Tags: c

My friend and I are working on a simple (turns out it is not as simple as it sounded to us at first) ATM project, which ,we thought, was suitable for beginners like us. This console application would let users to register an account, then log in to do other withdraw/deposit stuff. Our register function looks like this and it does write the customer info on a txt file, seperated by commas and square brackets.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct customers {
    int id[5];
    char fname[20];
    char lname[20];
    int password[4];
    int cashAmount[9];
};

int register(){
    int i=0;
    struct customers customer;
    *customer.id = rand()%99999;

    /*FILE *ids = fopen("ids.txt", "a+");
    fprintf(ids, "%d,\n", *customer.id);
    fclose(ids);*/

    FILE *cstm = fopen("musteriler.txt", "a+");

    scanf("%s %s %d %d", customer.fname, customer.lname, &customer.password, &customer.cashAmount);
    fprintf(cstm, "[%d\t%s\t%s\t%d\t%d];\n", *customer.id, customer.fname, customer.lname, *customer.password, *customer.cashAmount);

    getchar();
}
```

What we cannot achieve, or do not know how to achieve is how to find the line (or struct/chunk of info) that starts with the desired customer ID and take all the other corresponding info and put them in a struct back again.

The output txt file looks like this:

[image]

So, what we want to do is, once the customer with the ID 61 prompts to log in, they would enter the ID first, the program would then find the line (or chunk of info closed with square brackets), read all the data separated with whitespaces, put them back again in corresponding variables in a struct. Then we can do all kinds of stuff with these info (do a password check to let them in, or other banking operations). What route should we follow?

Comment: You will need a loop that reads the file, extracting one record at a time until you find a match.

Comment: Check the basic C function `fread`.

Comment: No, *not* `fread`, as that would perform an unformatted read, but the file uses formatted, variable-length records (with tab separators).  But `fscanf()` could be made to work if one were willing to assume that the file was well-formed.  Otherwise, `fgets()` would probably be the best choice for reading lines, possibly combined with `sscanf()` to parse them.

Comment: Is there specific reason you have to use this square brackets and semicolons file format and not CSV?

Comment: @JanneTuukkanen Good question. We tried to use CSV but CSV libraries and functions confused us a little bit, and we were not sure if it would come in handy using CSV instead of txt. So we had to come up with our own formatting. Should we do it with CSV, what are the advantages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I would use CSV-format instead and do something like this to read the file in

csv-format

```
41,cstfname1,cst1lname,9999,1234
61,cstfname2,cst2lname,88888,5678
...
```

---

```
char lineBuffer[255]; // assuming nobody has gigantic long names
int line = 0;
while (fgets(lineBuffer,sizeof(lineBuffer),fp))
{
  ++line;
  char* p = strtok(lineBuffer,","); // here CSV-format comes in handy
  if (atoi(p) == yourId)
  {
    // parse the rest of the line
    char* name = strtok(NULL,",");
    if (name != NULL)
    { 
      strcpy(customer.fname, name);
    }
    else
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Wrong format encountered in line %d\n", line);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ... rest of the fields
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in this answer I will assume that your input file format is like
`[user_id costumer_first_name costumer_last_name password cash_amount]`. Then using `int fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...)` is a good solution for this scenario. First goal for you is to read file word by word using given function. Example code link for this below (Tip: Please begin struct names with uppercase letter and use typedef!):
https://codeshare.io/5NbPqm
Also sharing screenshot in case of server crush:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU8Vs.png)
Good luck!

Comment: Please post code **directly in the answer as text**, not a link and/or an image.

Comment: Since I am new, I couldn't realise how to post a chunk of code in answer section. I'll try it soon.